# Select one of each type from collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor collection that has a field called `type`. I'm wondering if there's a way to select one document of each `type`. For example, if I had the following documents in my collection (sorted by descending `createdAt`)

```
Document #1: {type = "apple", createdAt: ...}
Document #2: {type = "apple", createdAt: ...}
Document #3: {type = "grape", createdAt: ...}
Document #4: {type = "orange", createdAt: ...}
Document #5: {type = "orange", createdAt: ...}
Document #6: {type = "grape", createdAt: ...}
Document #7: {type = "apple", createdAt: ...}
...
```

Then how could I select 3 documents each with a unique type? In this example, I would need Document #1, #3, and #4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first find all the [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) types with

```
var distinctTypes = db.mycollection.distinct("type");
```

and then you can loop through to push all the documents from `findOne` like so

```
var docs = [];
distinctTypes.forEach(function (thisType) {
  docs.push(db.mycollection.findOne({type: thisType});
});
```

From here you can alter the above code to specify which one you want if there are multiples of each type.

**UPDATE:** Since Meteor still doesn't support `distinct`, you can use the underscore `uniq` like so

```
var distinctTypes = _.uniq(Collection.find({}, {
    sort: {type: 1}, fields: {type: true}
}).fetch().map(function(x) {
    return x.type;
}), true);
```

Comment: FYI: `.distinct` works in native mongodb but not in Meteor. I ran into that limitation early on.

Comment: @MichelFloyd thanks for calling it out. I've updated answer. Hopefully Meteor will support it soon

Comment: Yes it's kind of an annoying oversight. afaik people have been asking for it for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps: first, you get the counts using `$group`, identified by `type`, then `$match` all that have count = 1.

```
db.fruit_collection.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        createdAt: { $gt: ISODate("2015-08-01T12:00:00Z") }
    }}, 
    { $group: {
        _id: "$type",
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}, 
    { $match: { 
        count: 1
    }}
]);
```

The first `$match` is there as an example, so you can ignore. The second and the third part should give you the desired result.

Comment: It sounds to me that he wants one document of each type no matter how many documents (1 or more) exist for each type. He didn't specify which document to pick when there are more than one of each type (random, first created, etc...).

Comment: Michel, you are right. In that case instead of `count: { $sum: 1 }`, the expression `type: {$first: "$type"}, obj_id: { $first: "$_id"}` should be used, and the last `{$match: ...}` omitted. This format will print the object id of the first record in the grouping. Also, other attributes may be added in the same way.