# mongoose retrieve one document of each type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of `batchId`s, say `[001, 002,003,...]`. Also imagine that my collection is like so:

```
{ batchId: 001, data: ... }
{ batchId: 001, data: ... }
{ batchId: 001, data: ... }
{ batchId: 002, data: ... }
{ batchId: 002, data: ... }
{ batchId: 003, data: ... }
{ batchId: 003, data: ... }
{ batchId: 003, data: ... }
```

Now, can I get first one document each of one `batchId`, so that the response is like this:

```
{ batchId: 001, data: ... }
{ batchId: 002, data: ... }
{ batchId: 003, data: ... }
```

I went through [Select one of each type from collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131604/select-one-of-each-type-from-collection) and the suggested answer was do `findOne` for each `batchId`. But is there any way I could do it in a single database fetch ?

NOTE: What I have done now is read everything, and then use Lodash' `_.uniqBy` to filter one each. Just needed to know if that is the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use mongoDB aggregation pipeline to fetch the first document of each type.

Use, `$group` with `$first`.

First use `$match` with `$in` to get all the documents corresponding to the array of `batchIds`.

Next, group by the `batchId` and take the data of the first document using `$first`.

```
Collection.aggregate([
    $match :{
        batchId : {
            $in : batchIdArray
        }
    },
    $group : {
        _id : "$batchId",
        batchId : { $first : "$batchId"},
        data : {$first : "$data}
    }
]);
```

Read MongoDB documentation on [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) for detailed information.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know!

Comment: @Dane sure, i am hoping this will work for you, and will achieve the result you want.